# If $AA^T$ is a diagonal matrix, what can be said about $A^TA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-congruences

I am trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679432/given-generalized-eigenvalues-eigenvectors-obtain-standard-eigenvalues-eigenvect) and any method I can think of requires a knowledge of $A^TA$ given that $AA^T=D$, where $D$ is diagonal and $A$ is a square matrix. I could not find anything useful in MSE or elsewhere and I was unable to do any progress by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A^TA = D$, then the columns of $A$ are orthogonal.  Hence, $A = O\Lambda$ for some diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. (In particular, if $A$ is nonsingular, we can take $\Lambda_{ii}$ to be the norm of the $i$th column of $A$, and let the $i$th column of $O$ be a normalized version of the $i$th column of $A$.)

Then, 
$$A^TA = \Lambda^TO^TO\Lambda = \Lambda^2 = D$$
so $\Lambda$ is the positive square root of $D$.  Thus, 
$$AA^T = O \Lambda \Lambda^T O^T = O D O^T.$$

Answer (score 9):

All you can say about $A^{\mathsf T}A$ is that is a symmetric matrix similar to $AA^{\mathsf T} = D$ (that is, it diagonalizes to $D$).

We can see this from $A$'s singular value decomposition: if $A = U\Sigma V^{\mathsf T}$, then $AA^{\mathsf T} = U \Sigma^2 U^{\mathsf T}$ and $A^{\mathsf T}A = V\Sigma^2 V^{\mathsf T}$, so both are similar to $\Sigma^2$.

To see that we cannot do better, note that if we replace $A$ by $AQ$, where $Q$ is any orthogonal matrix, then $(AQ)(AQ)^{\mathsf T} = AQQ^{\mathsf T}A^{\mathsf T} = AA^{\mathsf T} = D$, while $(AQ)^{\mathsf T}AQ = Q^{\mathsf T}(A^{\mathsf T}A)Q$, which is the conjugation of $A^{\mathsf T}A$ by an arbitrary orthogonal matrix $Q$.

---

In the case that $A$ is not necessarily square, we cannot even say this much, although from the singular value decomposition we can still conclude that $AA^{\mathsf T}$ and $A^{\mathsf T}A$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Although your answer is great, the @Strants' answer is more useful for my purposes, so I had to accept his answer even after I had accepted yours. Thank you.

Comment: No problem: that's what accepting answers is for.

Answer (score 6):

If you are expecting $A^\top A$ to be diagonal, here is a counterexample.
Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}$. Then $AA^\top$ is diagonal but $A^\top A$ is not.

Comment: @tobwin $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1\\2&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\-1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&8\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  Multiplying in the other order though gives $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}5&3\\3&5\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Comment: I was hoping it was diagonal @angryavian... Thank you.

Comment: This example actually works over any commutative ring, although $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&0}$ would make a simpler example.